# Qlikview: how do I join ODBC loaded data with excel loaded data?

Tags: qlikview

I seem to not be able to insert ODBC data onto a resident loaded table.

What is the correct way to add/append data onto a resident loaded table?

Any help appreciated.

***I've tried loading dimensions from ODBC with resident load, however I would normally get an error that those values do not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 2 tables have exactly the same column names then QlikView will automatically concatenate them. i.e. append the one onto the other.
Try this;

```
 ODBC_TABLE:
 sql select A,
      B,
      C
 from DB_TABLE_NAME;

 load A,
      B,
      C
 from EXCEL.XLS;
```

This will result in one table called ODBC_TABLE with columns A, B and C containing the data from both sources.

Or if you need extra columns from one of the tables you can force the 2 together using the concatenate() load prefix for the second table you load

```
 ODBC_TABLE:
 sql select A,
      B,
      C
 from DB_TABLE_NAME;
 concatenate(ODBC_TABLE)
 load A,
      B,
      C,
      D
 from EXCEL.XLS;
```

Resulting in one table called ODBC_TABLE with columns A, B, C and D containing all the data from the 2 sources and nulls in D for records from the first source

Comment: Hi Budac :), the problem is not in the field names in this case. I have right now two separate working qliks - one which has a list of data from multiple excels that shows pricing for various coded items, and I have a separate ODBC database, which has pricing info as well (pricing in these cases is basically for the same coded items, however the prices are not exactly the same - ones are from ODBC for the coded items in the database, the other prices are for coded items from excel lists (majority of coded items will match). To show both pricings next to the codes is the goal.

Comment: Hi, I tried it differently than before and I figured out how to actually rename it with the least effort and barely any script re-write. Thanks again, Budac! :) Though I'm still unsure whether I know _why_ one dimension was supposed to have a prefix of the table. Example - "TABLENAME.EAN" when the SQL showed a different name, I renamed  that name to EAN and it still was appended to a workable dimension "TABLENAME.EAN. I'd like to know that, if you could reply it to me. Hope I explained it enough.

Comment: I think I know what has happened. But if you can post a code snippet I'll have a much better chance of explaining exactly what happened. Otherwise it's just a guess

Comment: Hi, no need. I found this answer: Qualify and UnQualify statements are to avoid unnecessary joins on the fields,
which append table names in front of the field names. Thanks anyway, Budac! :)